# Line fitting python

Tags: curve-fitting

I have these two arrays x and y (pink scatter points), and I want to fit a line as shown in the figure (blue line). However, I have not been able to find the proper fit or a proper equation. I have tried exponentials, polyfits and nothing. Maybe someone here has an idea. Original x and y data are here.

x=[50.56457351, -25.94178241,  10.20492002,  -4.42553174,
-27.33151148, -29.9721279 ,  36.06962759,   7.56321785,
52.94172778,   1.99279668,  70.60954309, -41.28236289,
-28.56116707, -43.98117436,  19.52197933, -13.99493533,
-35.4383463 , -44.3050207 ,  -3.96679614,  14.88981502]

y=[-3.39506291,  5.07105136, 21.0870528 , 17.67702032,  0.03026157,
6.45900452, -0.19873009,  7.50795551, -1.82804242, -3.65200329,
-2.93492827, -5.86174941, -2.50507783, -3.43619693, -2.66194664,
-3.59860008, -0.19628881, -2.94505151, -2.3179664 , -2.29120004]

[image: plot]

Comment: Well, that is not a "function" in the sense of, e.g. `curve_fit` The standard fitting needs functions with `f: x->f(x)` i.e. a unique `y` for a given `x` This is definitively not the case here. You could rotate your data to get rid of this problem , but this is difficult to make for the general case and maybe impossible, depending on the type of data you expect. So probably you should go for a parametric curve, might be a spline or  Bézier-curve.

Comment: https://web.archive.org/web/20180403213813/http://jimherold.com/2012/04/20/least-squares-bezier-fit/

Comment: https://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo/